# Does temporary files created exist across tasks in an airflow DAG

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

Does airflow DAG retains temp file created across tasks.

My code is

```
//This task calls an external api and downloads data into download.csv, this temp file download.csv is created on the fly by task using open function in python
t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id=f"api_download",
        bash_command=f'api_download_lineitemstatus.py',
    )
//This task suppose to read download.csv created in the first task and insert into DB
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id=f"insert_into_DB",
        bash_command=f'python lineinsert.py',
    )
 t1 >> t2
```

I get this error for task t2
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'download.csv'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the two task are run in a same environment they should exist. If you are running on a Local executor you could verify is the file has been downloaded to the correct path and I advice to test your code before using a localexecutor to check that the file is there.

**If running in  a kubernetes executor**:

In a Kubernetes Executor, each task instance is run in its own pod on a Kubernetes cluster. The worker pod then runs the task, reports the result, and terminates. Therefore after the worker pods shuts everything inside the pod is lost except if you have configure it. Thus any file downloaded is lost.

The alternative is to create a single task that groups the actions you have on task 1 and task2.(you will gain time of creating and deleting pods)

Another option is to use S3/GCS/etc to store your files and recover it in the subsequent tasks.

Finally changing to a cellery executor or CeleryKubernetes could also be a solution.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/celery_kubernetes.html